# Как записать значение div в js и наоборот?

Tags: javascript, html

Ситуация такая: у меня есть 2-а div'a
`<div id="value1"></div>` и `<div id="value2"></div>`.
value1(div) имеет уже определенное число, мне нужно его записать в переменную js и умножить на 2. После умножения передать его в value2(div). Всё что я понял - как передать их друг другу...

```
var el = document.getElementById('value1');
var ea = document.getElementById("value2");
ea.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myvar = 2*document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML;
document.getElementById("value2").innerHTML = myvar;
```

Comment: спасибо, работает